# Painting to a panel

Tags: java, button, graphics, paint

So I have created a program that accepts the radius of a circle in a text box, creates the circle of a random color in a random spot and another button to clear the page of all circles. The problem I am having is with my overridden paint().

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;


public class PushPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JButton newb;
    private JButton clear;
    private JLabel label;
    private int x, y, width, r;
    private int color;
    private JTextField radius;

    public PushPanel()
    {
        newb = new JButton("New");
        clear = new JButton("Clear");
        radius = new JTextField(5);

        radius.addActionListener(new TextListener());
        newb.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        clear.addActionListener(new ButtonListener2());

        label = new JLabel ("Circle creator", SwingConstants.CENTER);

        add(radius);
        add (newb);
        add (clear);
        add(label);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

    }


    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            paintComponent(getGraphics());
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
        {
             Random rand = new Random();   
             int redValue = rand.nextInt(255); 
             int greenValue = rand.nextInt(255); 
            int blueValue = rand.nextInt(255); 
            Color clr = new Color(redValue, greenValue, blueValue);

            Random generator = new Random(101);
             x = generator.nextInt();
             y = generator.nextInt();
             width = r*2;

            page.setColor(clr);
            page.fillOval(x,y,width,width);
        }


    }

    public class ButtonListener2 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            paintComponent(getGraphics());
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
        {
            page.setColor(Color.white);
        }
    }

    public class TextListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            String text = radius.getText();
            r = Integer.parseInt(text);

        }
    }
}


This is the driver class, pretty basic

    public class Circle 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle stuff");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        PushPanel panel = new PushPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is that problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually told us what the problem is, but I would bet it's because your paintComponent() method is inside your ButtonListener class, not your PushPanel class.

Also, you should never call getGraphics() on a component, unless you really know what you're doing. Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/